# How to control differences between line and bar plot in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

Changing the attribute `kind = bar` to `kind = line` changes the x-axis characteristics in Python. How can I get the same line chart?

This is the base code:

```
import pandas as pd

dataframe.plot(
  x = "Panel",
  y = ["Total A",
       "Total B"],
  ylim=(0, 15),
  rot = 90,
  kind = "bar"
)
```

The output using `bar`:

[image]

The output **simply** changing to `line`:

[image]

Why do I get only some labels and not all as in the first image?

Comment: Thanks. I've added the base code.

Comment: As said before, pandas does not plot, matplotlib does. [You can explicity set the labels:](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html) `plt.xticks(np.arange(df.Panel.size), df.Panel)`. Not sure, why matplotlib decides to swallow some of them.

Comment: Can I add the missing labels in the above code? I.e. in a single call?

Comment: I don't know if you can enforce it directly from pandas. I doubt it because pandas gives matplotlib the whole list of labels, but I might be wrong in this assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going into the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html#pandas.DataFrame.plot), I saw that the keyword `xticks` is supported. To my surprise, the following works:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

#fake data generation
from pandas._testing import rands_array
np.random.seed(123)
n = 30
val1 = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=n)
val2 = np.random.randint(20, 40, size=n)
ind = rands_array(5, n)
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": val1, "B": val2, "Panel": ind})
print(df)


df.plot(
  x = "Panel",
  y = ["A", "B"],
  rot = 90,
  xticks=np.arange(df.Panel.size),
  kind = "line"
)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Sample output:

[image]